# form loop all and check radio + options

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a long form and trying to get the loop done. but i am not sure how to
check for options (dropdown) and radio type's, if exist, select the checked or selected and put it in the array.

Is there a better way to construct it? 
and when the loop is done, to pass the var for sending it in ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parameters = "";
var form = document.getElementById("someForm");
for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
    if(form.elements[i].value) {
        if(form.elements[i].type == "text" || form.elements[i].type == "select-one" || form.elements[i].type == "hidden")
            parameters = parameters + '&' + form.elements[i].name+'='+escape(form.elements[i].value);
        if((form.elements[i].type == "radio" || form.elements[i].type == "checkbox") && form.elements[i].checked)
            parameters = parameters + '&' + form.elements[i].name+'='+form.elements[i].value;
    }
}
```

I generally use something like this, if I need to ajax a form. 
Simply append parameters to the end of your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the way [jQuery does it](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js). Specifically you will want to look at the `serialize` (line 6260), `serializeArray` (line 6264) and `param` (line 6784) methods.

According to this [comparison of form serialization](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/comp/) in different JavaScript libraries, jQuery's implementation adheres to the W3C specification better than the competition.

Answer (score 0):

I agree in looking at jQuery, but maybe try implementing something yourself. You could get all inputs / textareas / selects within the form quite easily using jQuery:

```
// get all input fields, except buttons
var inputs = $("form input:not(:button)");
// get all dropdowns
var dropdowns = $("form select");
// get all text areas (i.e. "big" textboxes)
var textareas = $("form textarea");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this (I edited line 2 of [Sheldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60789/sheldon-ross)'s solution):

```
var parameters = "";
var form = document.someForm;
for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
    if(form.elements[i].value) {
        if(form.elements[i].type == "text" || form.elements[i].type == "select-one" || form.elements[i].type == "hidden")
            parameters = parameters + '&' + form.elements[i].name+'='+escape(form.elements[i].value);
        if((form.elements[i].type == "radio" || form.elements[i].type == "checkbox") && form.elements[i].checked)
            parameters = parameters + '&' + form.elements[i].name+'='+form.elements[i].value;
    }
}
```